# VSCode F8 function issue

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, key-bindings, powershell-7.2

I recently updated the latest version of PowerShell (7.2.5) as well as my version of VSCode to:

```
Version: 1.68.1 (user setup)
Commit: 30d9c6cd9483b2cc586687151bcbcd635f373630
Date: 2022-06-14T12:48:58.283Z
Electron: 17.4.7
Chromium: 98.0.4758.141
Node.js: 16.13.0
V8: 9.8.177.13-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.18363
```

After these updates, when I have my PowerShell 7.2.5 integrated terminal open and I highlight and run code from the editor using `f8`, the code runs as expected.  However, as soon as the code finishes running, all the code is then pasted into the terminal as if I were to run it again.  This issue does not happen if I do not use vscodes integrated terminal for PowerShell 7.2.5.

The example below illustrates the issue.

1. I highlighted the code.
2. I pressed `f8`.
3. The code runs as expected.
4. But then is copied out to the terminal

[image]

The only thing I can think of is the issue may be with a change to some keybindings between VSCode versions.  I have attached my default keybindings as I have no overriding keybindings.

Below are the only keybindings I have that relate to `f8`

```
{ "key": "alt+f8",                "command": "editor.action.marker.next",
                                     "when": "editorFocus" },
{ "key": "f8",                    "command": "editor.action.marker.nextInFiles",
                                     "when": "editorFocus" },
{ "key": "shift+alt+f8",          "command": "editor.action.marker.prev",
                                     "when": "editorFocus" },
{ "key": "shift+f8",              "command": "editor.action.marker.prevInFiles",
                                     "when": "editorFocus" },
{ "key": "alt+f8",                "command": "testing.goToNextMessage",
                                     "when": "editorFocus && testing.isPeekVisible" },
{ "key": "shift+alt+f8",          "command": "testing.goToPreviousMessage",
                                     "when": "editorFocus && testing.isPeekVisible" },
{ "key": "f8",                    "command": "PowerShell.RunSelection",
                                     "when": "editorTextFocus && editorLangId == 'powershell'" },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Powershell plugin version 2022.6.1 - you can roll back in the extension editor by installing the may version.

1. Open the extension tab,
2. Search for Powershell
3. Click the down arrow on the Unisntall and select Install another version
4. Select 2022.5.1
5. Reload when prompted.

This is discussed in the GitHub channel for the powershell plugin. https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/4041